# call SQL Adapter in hybrid app

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to get data from DB2. After calling the SQL adapter I got the following error in LogCat:

> Procedure invocation error. Class Cast:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject incompatible with
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Function

**Adapter XML**

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
    <driverClass>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver</driverClass>
    <url>jdbc:as400://host/HRCORE</url>
    <user>HRCORE</user>
    <password>HRCORE</password> 
</dataSourceDefinition>
```

After this error in LogCat I'm getting note from loadFailure function

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter : "SQLAdapter",
    procedure : "getTypeFromSubjectTabele",
    parameters : []
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
    onSuccess:this.loadSucess,
    onFailure:this.loadFailure,     
});
```

**Adapter implementation**

```
var getTypeFromSubjectTabele = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("SELECT type FROM subject");

function getTypeFromSubjectTabele(){
    WL.Logger.warn("INSIDE ADAPTER getTypeFromSubjectTabele");
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement: getTypeFromSubjectTabele,
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

Comment: You didn't add any actual implementation code... from the adapter impl.js file.

Comment: @IdanAdar  before  I did not supplement adapter impl.js file code because  mistake appears before WL.Logger.warn("INSIDE ADAPTER getTypeFromSubjectTabele"); and I don't see in server log this logger

Comment: like  a mobilefirst server I'm using  WAS full profile which locates remotely

Comment: You need to change the log level in the server. Go to the servers view in eclipse > open the development sever entry and double click on sever configuration. Change from audit to info. Also change from we.logger.warn to .info

Comment: Start by getting it to work locally.

Comment: @IdanAdar I've got the same error in mobilefirst server development console. [ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project Adapters]SQLAdapter/getTypeFromSubjectTabeleFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project Adapters]
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject cannot be cast to org.mozilla.javascript.Function
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project Adapters]nulljava.lang.ClassCastException: org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaObject cannot be cast to org.mozilla.javascript.Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **think** the problem is that you are using the same name for the variable and the function (see section "[Function Declaration Overrides Variable Declaration When Hoisted](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/)"). Give each a unique name and see if this solved this specific issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed variable name and this solved the problem